# Getting Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException while downloading a pdf using Puppeteer

Tags: php, laravel, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to download a pdf. I have installed the puppeteer using the following commands.

```
1.curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
2.sudo apt-get install -y nodejs gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget libgbm-dev
3.sudo npm install --global --unsafe-perm puppeteer
4.sudo chmod -R o+rx /usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium
```

But in the end i am getting the following errors. I don't know why.

```
The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node '/home/azahar/Desktop/Mazegeek Project/neomeet-web/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.js' '{"url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/pdf\/meeting-preview\/7","action":"pdf","options":{"path":"\/home\/azahar\/Desktop\/Mazegeek Project\/neomeet-web\/storage\/private\/temporary\/meeting_preview_7.pdf","args":[],"viewport":{"width":800,"height":600},"format":"A4","waitUntil":"networkidle0"}}'" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: /home/azahar/Desktop/Mazegeek Project/neomeet-web/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded at /home/azahar/Desktop/Mazegeek Project/neomeet-web/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:106:111 at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (/home/azahar/Desktop/Mazegeek Project/neomeet-web/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:90:21) at async Frame.goto (/home/azahar/Desktop/Mazegeek Project/neomeet-web/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:417:16) at async Page.goto (/home/azahar/Desktop/Mazegeek Project/neomeet-web/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:784:16) at async callChrome (/home/azahar/Desktop/Mazegeek Project/neomeet-web/vendor/spatie/browsershot/bin/browser.js:171:9)
```

I am using laravel 7, PHP 7.4

Comment: The puppeteer process is timing out after 30 seconds. Try one of the suggested solutions [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1106/how-to-solve-puppeteer-timeouterror-navigation-timeout-of-30000-ms-exceeded).

Comment: Were you ever able to find a resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In [Browsershot, you can set the timeout](https://spatie.be/docs/browsershot/v2/miscellaneous-options/setting-the-timeout) like this:

```
Browsershot::url('https://example.com')->timeout(120)->save($pathToImage);
```